# what does the symbol # inside a class javascript?

Tags: javascript

what does it means declare variables with the symbol **"#"** in javascript? I am learning about builder pattern and I found it with some examples. Also I saw that the variables are calls with this.#color.

**#** symbol is different to declare variable with let or var? what is the difference?

thanks

```
class Car {

    #color = null
    #spoiler = null
    #fuelType = null
    #productionDate = null

}
```

Comment: It marks the fields as private: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Private class members](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields)

```
class ClassWithPrivate {
  #privateField;
  #privateFieldWithInitializer = 42;

  #privateMethod() {
    // …
  }

  static #privateStaticField;
  static #privateStaticFieldWithInitializer = 42;

  static #privateStaticMethod() {
    // …
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It means private variable.

```js
class Car{
    #color = "#FFF";
    // a getter to read the value
    get color() { return this.color; }
}
```

If you try to affect the private variable from outside of this class it will fail including passing a method inside this class to another system. I will say that debuggers such as the browser's console is still able to see these values for debugging.

E.G

```js
class Car{
    #color = "#FFF";
    // a getter to read the value
    get color() { return this.color; }

    #setColor = (color) => {this.#color = color}
    
    passColorSetter = (fn) => {
        fn(this.#setColor); // this is not allowed 
        // as the referenced function in fn is not defined in this class
    }
}
```

So they are truly private unlike the hacks that used to exist
E.G

```js
function Car{
    let color = "#FFF";
    this.getColor = function(){ return color; }

    let setColor = (c) => {color = c}
    
    passColorSetter = (fn) => {
        fn(setColor); // this would work
        // and allow the fn referenced function to call setColor
    }

}
```